# Is there a way to assign `AgentWork` while `UserServicePresence` is in `isAway` state

Tags: apex, omnichannel

```
AgentWork[] agentWork = new List<AgentWork>();
for (UserServicePresence usp : [
  SELECT Id, ServicePresenceStatus.MasterLabel, UserId, IsAway
  FROM UserServicePresence
  WHERE
    IsCurrentState = TRUE
    // AND IsAway = FALSE
    AND UserId IN :userIdToCaseMap.keySet()
]) {
  caseAvailabilityMap.put(userIdToCaseMap.get(usp.UserId).Id, true);
  agentWork.add(
    new AgentWork(
      UserId = usp.UserId,
      ServiceChannelId = channelId,
      WorkItemId = userIdToCaseMap.get(usp.UserId).Id,
      ShouldSkipCapacityCheck = true
    )
  );
}

if (!agentWork.isEmpty())
  insert agentWork;
```

If the user that has the `AgentWork` assigned is in an away status we get an error `FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The agent's status is not associated with the channel for this work.: Service Channel ID: [ServiceChannelId]` but it would be nice to still be able to assign the record regardless of `isAway` type status.